# Backpack for Laravel (select2_multiple)

Tags: php, laravel

I need to select multiple users and display the names as developers. But I get this error.

> Exception
> Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: D:\Laravel\BoomTech\bug-tracker\resources\views\project_issues.blade.php)

Code that should show the name/s of users:

```
{{ $issue->developer->name }}
```

Issues table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('issues', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->foreignId('project_id');
        $table->foreignId('submitted_by_id');
        $table->foreignId('developer_id');
        $table->string('title', 255);
        $table->string('comment', 255)->nullable();
        $table->mediumText('description');
        $table->text('status');
        $table->text('type');
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('deleted_at')->nullable();
    });
}
```

Issue User (pivot table):

```
Schema::create('issue_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->foreignId('user_id');
        $table->foreignId('issue_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
    });
```

Issue Model:

```
public function developer()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'issue_user', 'issue_id', 'user_id');
}
```

IssueCRUDController:

```
CRUD::addField([    // Select2Multiple = n-n relationship (with pivot table)
        'label' => "Developer",
        'type' => 'select2_multiple',
        'name' => 'developer', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model

        // optional
        'entity' => 'developer', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'model' => "App\Models\User", // foreign key model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
       'pivot' => false, // on create&update, do you need to add/delete pivot table entries?
    ]);
```

Comment: `BelongsToMany` suggests there will be more than one `User` attached. So `$issue->developer` is a Collection of `User` instances. Also note you don't need to specify column names when defining relationships, unless they are non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

This is many to many relationships so you need to do like this:

```
public function developers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'issue_user', 'issue_id', 'user_id');
}


@foreach($issue->developers() as $developer)
{{ $developer->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I am still getting this error:

ErrorException
Attempt to read property "name" on bool (View: D:\Laravel\BoomTech\bug-tracker\resources\views\project_issues.blade.php)

Comment: @foreach($issue->developers as $developer)
{{ $developer->name }}
@endforeach   try this